# Extract data from large nonrectangular text

Tags: python, matlab, extract

I have a large non-rectangular text file where I need to extract data from. I prefer to do it in Python but Matlab is good as well. 
The data that I would like to extract, from names that are "relevant”, from the example below looks like this:

CLASS       MIKE  (2 columns)
01      02  (last 2 numbers of CLASS and MIKE)
03          04
05      06

Below is an example of the text file, the paragraphs with the name "relevant" occur randomly. Each record is separated by two empty lines.

```
-CLASS 36463601  
-NAME RELEVANT  
-FAX -PHONE OSCAR -NO 36468500  
-FAX -PHONE LIMA -NO 745674600  
-FAX -PHONE DELTA -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE MIKE NO 74757502   
-HOME 3232


-CLASS 36463603  
-NAME RELEVANT  
-FAX -PHONE OSCAR -NO 36468500  
-FAX -PHONE LIMA -NO 745674600  
-FAX -PHONE DELTA -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE BRAVO -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE MIKE NO 74757504     
-HOME 3232  


-CLASS 36463600  
-NAME NOT RELEVANT  
-FAX -PHONE OSCAR -NO 36468500  
-FAX -PHONE LIMA -NO 745674600  
-FAX -PHONE DELTA -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE BRAVO -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE MIKE NO 74757503   
-HOME 3232  


-CLASS 36463605  
-NAME RELEVANT  
-FAX -PHONE OSCAR -NO 36468500  
-FAX -PHONE LIMA -NO 745674600  
-FAX -PHONE DELTA -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE BRAVO -NO 46778400  
-FAX -PHONE MIKE NO 74757506     
-HOME 3232
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about looping through the lines from top to bottom and remembering whether the last `RELEVANT` was preceded by `NAME`? If so, just get the third word if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did not try anything so I am not giving any code. But I can share algorithm I would use to parse the data. With this, I believe you should be able to ask specific questions when you run into trouble of implementing something. Also, I tried to stay close to pythonic expressions, so everything should be easy to convert into actual code.

This will crawl through whole file and buffer lines up to two empty ones. Then store buffer if relevant line was present during the processing. It actually is a simple state machine. `lines` and `relevant_records` can be python lists.

```
1. For each `line` in text file:
 1.1. if `line` is empty then `empty_lines++` else append `line` to `lines`.
 1.2. if `empty_lines == 2` then:
   1.2.1. if `record_relevant` then output/save `lines` 
          (e.g relevant_records.append(lines))
   1.2.2. `record_relevant = false`
   1.2.3. `empty_lines = 0`
   1.2.4. `lines = []` #clear buffer
 1.3. if `line` contains `NAME RELEVANT` then `record_relevant = true`.
```

You should also call `1.2.1-4` after last record if it is not followed by two empty lines.

You can group it up into functions and classes to make it prettier and better designed and maintainable.